# Why are Ubuntu upgrades so large (compared to Android)?

Tags: upgrade

Upgrading Ubuntu to a new distribution entails a download of about 2GB each time while Android upgrades require a download of a few hundred MB's.

Android is of course a smaller operating system but another difference is that an Android upgrade only upgrades the base OS (kernel and the fundamental apps) and not the user installed apps. But an Ubuntu upgrade updates every single application and library, it seems that it even reinstalls the ones which have not been moved to a new version.

My question is about the latter difference: why is this and does it give any advantage over the Android model?

Comment: I am not sure that it actually gives any advantage (apart maybe from some cleanliness of the system). I think that you will be welcome to develop some tools for the Ubuntu upgrade to make it more "Android-style" and less net expensive :)

Comment: Consider that a distro like Ubuntu is built using a wide variety of development tools and libraries, whereas in the case of Android, it's essentially just the API that the Android system provides that's being used. The apps that have not had upstream upgrades still need to rebuilt using upgraded libraries, if only for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Android uses something called ARM as it component setup.   ARM uses much less hardware because of the smaller space.  Because of this Ubuntu on Android doesn't need to be as big.  Also most phone devices don't have more than 1 gb of storage space on a common level.  We are also talking about mobile data.   No one wants 2gb eaten on a single update.